# get total childs items form table , mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with child culmon

if child culmon = 0 , so the it's Main Item , else

the item is child of the other item

Table Items  :

```
-------------------------------
id  |  title             |  child
1   | A main item 1      |   0
2   | B main item 2      |   0
3   | K child of item_2  |   2
4   | R child of item_1  |   1
5   | Q child of item_1  |   1
--------------------------------
```

I want one query to get data like this if it's possible :

```
   ---------------------------------
    + Main item 1  (total 2 childs)
        - R
        - Q
    + Main item 2  (total 1 child)
        - K
```

I did a lot of searchs but I did not get it !
I can use join if there is two tables , but I did not know how can I do that if I use just one table .. umm , any help will be most appreciated ..

**EDIT ..  I did this : **

my table like this :

```
-------------------------------
id  |  title             |  child
1   | main_item1         |   0
2   | main_item2         |   0
3   | child item         |   1
4   | another child item |   1
5   | child for main2    |   2
--------------------------------
```

Query :

```
  SELECT *
  FROM `items` AS `t1`
  INNER JOIN `items` AS `t2`

  WHERE `t1`.`child` = `t2`.`id` and t2.user_id = $user_id
```

and I get this :

```
-main_item_1
-main_item_1
-main_item2
```

any help ?

------------------------ SOLVED ! --------------------------------------------

sorry I can not answer my own question , so I edited my question here ..

Thank you guys for your help ..

and thanks for @Shi ( I made changes for his code :)  )

I just did this simple query to get all of my main items and total of children for each main item .. like this :

```
  SELECT *,
     (SELECT COUNT(1)
      FROM `items`
      WHERE child = t1.id )
      AS  total_childs

  FROM `itmes` AS `t1`
  where `t1`.`child` = 0

  GROUP BY t1.id
```

and I get data like this :

- main_item1 (total children : 2)
- main_item2 (total children : 1)

then I did another query to get all items ( children items )

and inside template page I just write IF statement to get children of each item 
some thing like that (I use Smarty Template) ;

```
{foreach from=$items item=i} 
{$i.title} ( total children : {$i.total_childs} )

// did another foreach to get children 
{foreach from=$children item=c} 
  {if $c.child eq $i.id}
  <li> {$c.title} </li>
  {/if}
{/foreach}


{/foreach}
```

of course if there is a better way to do that , it's nice if someone help us with it :)

thanks again ..

Comment: Ahmad: Your Inner Join is looking good although I prefer ON instead of WHERE. If you aren't satisfied with the result you should add per tree height another INNER JOIN to your query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the table with itself:

SELECT * FROM `table` AS `t1` INNER JOIN `table` AS `t2` ON `t1`.`child` = `t2`.`id`;

If you want to store larger and deeper nested trees, I recommend using [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).

Comment: sorry I did not get it , how can I display data in html , I use smarty so I did that .. {foreach from=$items item=i} <li>{$i.title}</li> {/foreach} ....  but I got a list of items and some of them repeated ! .. thank you Shi , I think I have to make some edits on your query but but I dont where exactly :/

Comment: @Jitamaro , thank you , I did not see your first comment up there , sorry for that .. yes I changed where to ON , but I got the same result .. thanks ..

Answer (score 1):

For example if you want to get the count of children of `id` 1 then use this query

```
select count(child) from Items where child ='1'
```

to get the titles of children of `id` 1 then use this query

```
select title from Items where child ='1'
```

to get count of children of all rows grouped by `child` values use

```
select count(id),child from Items where child in (1,2,3,4,5) group by child
```

the following query will show you all elements which are children

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.title, t1.child
FROM `Items` AS `t1`
INNER JOIN `Items` AS `t2`
WHERE `t1`.`child` = `t2`.`id`
AND t1.id
IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
```

Comment: Would this work with IN to for example WHERE child IN (1,2,3,4,5)? Please can you post an example output of this query?

Comment: how can I do that if I want to get list of all items and every item has total of his children like this : main_item1(2 childs)main_item3(4childs) and so on .. not to get total of specific main item ..

Comment: @Ahmad try using group by. see my comment to Jitamaro. i ll try to run this on my system

Comment: @lovesh , thank you , yes I use group by t1.child .. and I get just the main items , its good , but how can I get the total of children of each main item ? and children themselves ? thanks again ..

Comment: @Ahmad As far as i think the format u asked for in ur question is not possible because it is hierarchical and  SQL just return rows but you can get the count of children and names of all children in 2 separate queries. this is what i think at this point of time. try looking in the chat room for help

Comment: lovesh: Of course it's possible. See my comment to OP question!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It won't work with trees but should works for 2-level if child always > id:

```
$lastid=-1,$names=array();
$a=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tblname ORDER BY child ASC');
while($b=mysql_fetch_assoc($a)){
    if(!$b['child']){
         $names[$b['id']]=$b['name']; continue;
    }
    if($lastid!=$b['child'])
        print 'Childs of '.$names['child'].'<br>';
    print $b['name'].'<br>';
    $lastid=$b['child'];
}
```